# Checking for items in tables Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have an input file

```
Corn Fiber 17
Beans Protein 12
Milk Protien 15
Butter Fat 201
Eggs Fat 2
Bread Fiber 12
Eggs Cholesterol 4
Eggs Protein 8
Milk Fat 5
```

This is loaded into a table. I can then run commands to check the value of the items. For example `>print(foods.Eggs.Fat)
2`

What I need to do is be able to search if an item is already in the table. I have a function that checks if the table has a value, but it doesn't seem to be working. My code:

```
  file = io.open("food.txt")

    function has_value (tab, val)
    for index, value in ipairs(tab) do
        if value == val then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

    foods = {}
    for line in file:lines() 
        do
            local f, n, v = line:match("(%a+) (%a+) (%d+)")
            if foods[f] then
                foods[f][n] = v
            else
                foods[f] = {[n] = v}
            end
        end
    file:close()

    if has_value(foods, "Eggs") then
        print("Yes")
    else
        print("No")
    end
```

Even if the table does contain the item, I still am getting false returned from the function. In the example above, `if has_value(names, "Eggs") then` is printing "No" even when I know Eggs is in the table. Where is my error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `value` in this case, when really you should be looking for `key`.

```
function has_key(table, key)
    return table[key]~=nil
end
```

This function should do what you need it to, and much faster than searching for values, too!

Comment: I think you mean `nil`, instead of `null`, even though this typo has the same effect if you haven't defined `null`...

Comment: You are correct, good spot. I've been writing Java too much lately.